# Convert text column value (12 hours) to 24 hours from varchar column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

In my existing SQL Server database, there is a column like this:

- Column name and type: `meeting_time varchar(22)`
- Values stored in different format like `02:30:PM / 2:30:PM / 14:00:AM / 10:00:00:AM / 9:2:PM`

I am doing migration related work. In the existing database this kind of values were stored. I want to convert those into 24 hours format.

When I tried with stuff command with combination of IIF. It keep on increasing and I don't know the latest db has some other values. Since existing application, values can be entered by user and stored it in the database.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual problem is that you store times as strings instead of `time` values. The database shouldn't care about formatting, this should be left to the *client* application. Only the client application knows how the end user wants to display times. In fact, the customer may want to switch formats just by changing a setting

Comment: You could cast all these values to time if there wasn't a `:` before `PM`, eg `select  cast('02:30 PM' as time)` and `select  cast('9:2 PM' as time)` work. `14:00:AM` isn't a valid time. Is this an actual value? Is `AM` treated as junk in this case? If so, you'll have to clean up such weird data before converting to `time` or any other text format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must convert values stored in meeting_time column into valid time format. Example *02:30:PM* to *02:30 PM*, *10:00:00:AM* to *10:00:00 AM*. I think you could use

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ' AM'), ':PM', ' PM')
```

Then convert it to TIME data type

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ' AM'), ':PM', ' PM') AS TIME)
```

And then format the converted time as format that you want (the value **108** in below CONVERT function specifies the 24-hour time format)

```
CONVERT(varchar(22), CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ' AM'), ':PM', ' PM') AS TIME), 108)
```

If you are using MS SQL Server 2012 (or newer) and you also want to try converting invalid value, then we could used TRY_CAST instead CAST

```
 CONVERT(varchar(22),
        IIF(TRY_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ' AM'), ':PM', ' PM') AS TIME) IS NULL, 
            TRY_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ''), ':PM', '') AS TIME),
            CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(meeting_time, ':AM', ' AM'), ':PM', ' PM') AS TIME)) 
      , 108)
```

Comment: +1 and thank you for the good answer. But some column has invalid data like `14:00:AM`. When converting it into time, it throws error. Do you have any idea to handle this.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server that you are using? From SQL Server 2012, there is function TRY_CAST, you can use it instead of CAST. In case of invalid value, it will return NULL.